# assigning task of writing thank-you letters to staff members

Tags: civicontribute, contacts, activities

In our NGO, we write thank you letters by hand.
When I build a search that contains all contacts which donated in the last 2 months, all I can do is send them a Thank-you email automatically. I would prefer matching these contacts (around 200) to staff members (around 20), which will then write thank you letters by hand.

Any ideas how this could be achieved? 
Do I have to create a CiviRules-action?(https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-action/)

Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Kudos to your organization for hand-writing the thank you notes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CiviRules will indeed allow you to automatically create an activity when a new contribution is added. I assume there is an algorithm for which team member should be selected, I think you would need to create a customized action to make that happen!

Comment: Okay, i will try that :)

Comment: Let me know if you need any assistance writing your own CiviRules action